# Linq syntax getting error

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to use truncate table command and searching for it and found solution like this

```
context.Entities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dc.Entities);
and 
context.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM EntityName");
or
context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE EntityName");
```

But i didn't get it these methods in LINQ. what is context here?

in sql we use this syntax

```
Truncate table tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

`context` would be an instance of the relevant database-specific class which extends [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx). The LINQ to SQL designer will create that class for you.

I would strongly advise that you read a tutorial on LINQ to SQL before trying to write any code - it will explain the data context and its *purpose* so that you can use LINQ to SQL properly.

EDIT: Okay, you've now explained that you're using Entity Framework, not LINQ to SQL (as per your tags). That explains why you're not seeing the LINQ to SQL methods...

Comment: I agree with you but it doesn't show any method like ExecuteCommand or Entities etc

Comment: Yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand(v=VS.100).aspx and regarding entities, you might be confused about Linq to Entities (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) vs Linq to SQL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx). Enjoy the read!

Comment: @RizwanShahid: It sounds like you may well *not* have a class which extends `DataContext`...

Comment: @Jon Look at this code { EPManagerEntities db; db.Logs } where db is my datacontext and logs is my table now i want to truncate my table how i can do this?

Comment: @RizwanShahid: Well, that's not valid code to start with - and I suggest you edit it into your question, too. What does the declaration of `EPManagerEntities` look like? Are you *sure* you're using LINQ to SQL rather than the Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using mvc2.0 with Entity Framework and EPManagerEntities is my class name which extend my tables and column of my Database

Comment: @RizwanShahid: So if you're using Entity Framework, why did you tag your question LINQ to SQL? `ExecuteCommand` is part of LINQ to SQL, not Entity Framework...

Comment: @RizwanShahid: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. But it's really important that to start with you know which LINQ provider you're using - apart from anything else, it means you can consult the right documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using Linq-2-sql to throw raw sql commands at the database is possible but in this case linq-2-sql does not really give you any benefits. You may as well use plain Ado.Net in this case.

Anyway, If you have a real linq-2-sql datacontext it WILL show you the ExecuteCommand but you need to create your datacontext first.

Something like:

```
  using (notebookDataContext db = new notebookDataContext())
        { 
           db.ExecuteCommand( commandString, params);
         }
```